# Bootstrap - "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

A problem that many people have had, but I can't figure it out.

I get the following error in Chrome Developer Tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function **-----**
>   bootstrapwizard.js:3
>
> (anonymous function) **-----** jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
>
> m.Callbacks.j **-----** jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
>
> m.Callbacks.k.fireWith **-----** jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
>
> m.extend.ready **-----** jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 J

**I have tried the following:**

1) Moving the script into a own js-file

2) Replacing where I include "jQuery", "Bootstrap" and "script"

3) Searching for online solutions

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

*Thanks*

[The page can be found here. Its on Norwegian, but the bar is on English.](http://tinyurl.com/p9sb9em)

**Header**

```
 <!-- jQuery --->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

        <!-- Boostrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery scrips -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/hideheader.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/bootstrapwizard.js"></script>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index+1;
            var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
            $('#rootwizard').find('.bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
        }});
    });
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="container">
    <div id="rootwizard">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Forth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Fifth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Sixth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Seventh</a></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
            6
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
            7
        </div>
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>
            <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
            <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you really put your script files inside a folder named stylesheet_directory?

Comment: @InvernoMuto Hehe, no. I haven't understood wordpress so much yet. "Stylesheet_directory" is the theme folder :)

Comment: If it's not in there then you aren't including jquery according to your code. Which would break your page.

Comment: The code, script and everything should be there. http://tinyurl.com/p9sb9em - Scroll down till you see the bar. Sorry about the language on this page, but the bar etc. has not been touched, so that one is on English.

Comment: I believe u're bootstrapWizard js file is not complete, try downloading another version.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the page you described, there is no call for the bootstrapWizard.js file,
You need to add it either to your scrips, or load it from a CDN link such as:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js

edit: There is a call for bootstrapWizard but it is not the same file. It contains only the "onload" function for it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the bootstrapWizard was included in the boostrap.js, but that clears it up. I did the changed, also changed a little bit in the onload bootstrapWizard.js, and then added a lot of CSS. It appears that some of the CSS was not included in the bootstrap css-file. (Any idea why?). But anyways: Problem solved. Thanks :)